# tan pronto como vs en cuanto vs ni bien

Tags: sinónimos

Is there any difference in meaning between "tan pronto como", "en cuanto" and "ni bien" ? Example:

- Pagaré tu boleto tan pronto como / en cuanto / ni bien hagas la reserva. (= I will pay for your ticket as soon as you make the reservation)

Comment: I see no difference at all. They all mean the same thing.

Comment: I had never heard "ni bien"!  Between the other two, I feel like "tan pronto como" is a more meticulous instruction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They all mean the same.

As far as I can tell, the difference is that they are used in different regions. For instance aparente001 mentions above to never have heard "ni bien". My experience, having grown up in Argentina, is the opposite: "ni bien" is the most common, "en cuanto" is also common, and "tan pronto como" is understandable but sounds weird.

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer "en cuanto", which is the more neutral one. "tan pronto como" looks like a loan directly taking words from English. "Ni bien" is less common, maybe literary or outdated, perhaps a regional preference.

Of course, in slang Chilean Spanish, you would say "Pagaré el pasaje 'al tiro'" :-)

Comment: +1 from me, and welcome to the site, ellamir!